# how to get the innerText in jquery rather than textContent

Tags: jquery

i have a `DOM` structure as shown below, which keeps repeating

```
<label>hello world</label>
<span class="labelVal">
john and tomato enterprise
<span id="more" class="map" onclick="showAbc('3631381');" style="color: #c0392f;">+More</span>
<span id="ent" style="display: none;">
good will and enterprise
</span>
<span class="seeMap" onclick="stop=true;" style="display: none; color: #c0392b;">
some next coming</span>
</span>
```

i want to grab the `john and tomato enterprise` from the `html`.   when i `console.log()` i'm able to see `innerText:"john and tomato enterprise +More"`  my question is how to get it.  here is a `console.log()` image

[image]

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ov09jye4/2/

please see the jsfiddle. i don't know how to delete snippet(so it is remained)

```js
console.log($('label:contains("hello world")').next('span'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>hello world</label>
<span class="labelVal">
john and tomato enterprise
<span id="more" class="seeOnMapLink" onclick="showAbc('3631381');" style="color: #c0392b;">+More</span>
<span id="moreauthorisedDelerDesc3631381" style="display: none;">
good will and enterprise
</span>
<span class="seeMap" onclick="stop=true;" style="display: none; color: #c0392b;">
some next coming</span>
</span>
```

Comment: updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ov09jye4/3/  --                           text()-->http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get child nodes including text nodes then target first text node using [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) to get underlying DOM element and use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)property.

```
//Get the underlying DOM element
var element = $('label:contains("hello world")').next('span').contents().get(0);

//Get the node value
var value = element.nodeValue;
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hrubkga3/)

Comment: is this the method to access `innerText` in `jquery` ?

Comment: i don't know so i'm asking you don't mind i like your answer

Comment: @user5405873, You are entitled to ask for clarification, Its mix of jQuery and native JavaScript.

Comment: after using `$` as a selector i'm pretty conform it is `jQuery` , so i asked you above question

Answer (score 0):

if your HTML block is exactly like what you show, you can pickup the html content and strip it like this:

```
$('.labelVal').html().replace(/<span.*/,'');
```